# Pass an SQL query to php PDO function and execute

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have two pages. One contains the function to perform a query to the database. The other page contains the actual query declared into a variable.

How do I pass the query on page two to the function on page one and execute from there?

Here is the query on page two;

```php
$findFilter = SELECT * FROM products WHERE `dateCreated`>=SUBDATE(timestamp(now()), INTERVAL 730 HOUR) AND productCategory = 2
```

And here is my function on page one;

```php
public function action($action){
        $search = $action;
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($search);
        $stmt->execute([$action]);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 2 pages?

Comment: This is unnecessary `if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)`

Comment: Seems like page two should include page one to make use of the function. Or perhaps you'd need to post to page one from page two. Don't know, since we know nothing about your actual use case.

Comment: @Dharman, there are two different pages. One holds the variable and the other holds the function.

Comment: you need **two** parameters for this function, the sql query and the data for it. Doing $query=$data makes absolutely no sense

Comment: I don't know what that means. Perhaps you could explain the question more with some better examples or even screenshots